# Forward Reference of Type Parameter in Java Generics

Tags: java, generics

According to Java Generics FAQ
http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ302 
a type parameter cannot be forward-referenced in this way

```
<A extends B, B> // error
```

but it is ok to have

```
<A extends List<B>, B> // ok
```

These two examples are verified with the latest `jdk 1.6.0_24`.

My question is, where in the language spec this is specified, implied, or deductible(i.e. if it is untrue, other things can blow up). I can't find it anywhere.

*Update*

In javac7, it is allowed. Intuitively, the order of type parameters doesn't matter; the type system requires that there's no cyclic dependencies among type variables: `<A extends B, B extends A>`. Previously, this can be guaranteed by forbidding forward reference. Apparently javac 7 is improved to relax the ordering, while detecting cycles regardless of ordering.

Comment: So it appears that this rule is well known by java generics guys, but they forgot to put it in the language spec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is true.  I looked over the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html) and in §6.3 there's this discussion of the scopes of type parameters:

> **The scope of an interface's type parameter is the entire declaration of the interface including the type parameter section itself**. Therefore, type parameters can appear as parts of their own bounds, or as bounds of other type parameters declared in the same section.
>
> **The scope of a method's type parameter is the entire declaration of the method, including the type parameter section itself**. Therefore, type parameters can appear as parts of their own bounds, or as bounds of other type parameters declared in the same section.
>
> **The scope of a constructor's type parameter is the entire declaration of the constructor, including the type parameter section itself**. Therefore, type parameters can appear as parts of their own bounds, or as bounds of other type parameters declared in the same section.

(My emphasis).

This suggests that in the declaration

that `B` is indeed in scope when writing `A extends B`.

Furthermore, §4.4 of the JLS says, when referring to the bound on a type variable, that

> The bound consists of either a **type variable**, or a class or interface type T

Which suggests that not only is `B` in scope in `<A extends B, B>`, but that it's a perfectly legal bound on `A`.

Finally, to top things off, this code compiles in `javac`:

```
public class Test {
     public static <A extends B, B> A test(B obj) {
         return null;
     }
}
```

So I'm pretty sure that this is perfectly legal Java code and that the example you've linked to is either wrong or is referring to something else.

Hope this helps, and let me know if there's a flaw in my reasoning!

Comment: but it doesn't compile in my javac1.6 u21 b06. "illegal forward reference"

Comment: @irreputable- Hmmm, that's really weird.  Am I misinterpreting the relevant parts of the JLS I've cited?  Or is there a bug in your `javac` implementation?

Comment: `javac 1.6.0_20`.  I don't know what the versioning means; are you using a beta version of a new version?

Comment: @irreputable- Positive; I just double-checked it.  Are you compiling my minimal test case above, or something else?  If it's something else, are you sure that there isn't something else causing the error?  And if it is some other code, if you're comfortable doing so, could you post a link to it so that I could try compiling it?

Comment: I'm compiling your test code exactly, in default package. error points to the 1st `B`.

Comment: @irreputable- What OS are you on?  And where are you getting these versions of `javac`?  I'd like to try them out if that's possible.

Comment: windows 7 64 bit. jdk 6 update 24 from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html - but I'm also very surprised by your javac!

Comment: Looks like some of the compiler developers took the text in the generics FAQ and implemented in the compiler.

Comment: now it's working in javac 7. the limitation in javac 5 seems to be a shortcut way to exclude cyclic dependencies among type variables.

Answer (score 0):

It is completely legal, say more, you can imagine that A extends C which is generally extends B.
So what would you say about  when C extends B?