# How to express that type T must be of type U?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-7

Is there a way with Java generics to tell the compiler that type `T` must be of type `U`?  E.g.

```
public class Whatever<T, U> {

    T specific;
    U moreGeneral;

}
```

Now, I want to ensure that T is a subclass of `U`.  Is there a way to specify this?

Comment: You are looking for [Bounded Type Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html).

Comment: If you are going to downvote me, please say why.  that's just courtesy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply use

```
public class Whatever<T extends U,U>
```

Comment: This won't work. This will throw illegal forward reference to U.

Comment: I thought so (first answered reversing the order), but just tried, and it works. Try by yourself, it compiles both ways (used JDK 8)

Comment: @kuriouscoder 1.5? Haven't you found an older version? :D

Comment: Beats me. Now I am digging the release on when it was fixed. Incidentally, I happened to be on a machine with an older one.

Comment: @kuriouscoder Also works with JDK 7, so look at the changelog of JDK 6 it should be there

Comment: There is another post related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501836/possible-java-compiler-bug-program-does-not-compile-with-some-compilers and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201687/forward-reference-of-type-parameter-in-java-generics

Apparently, it was fixed in JDK 1.7

Answer (score 4):

To clarify, the following would do the trick on  JDK pre 1.7. When trying to switch the order of declaration of U and T I get `illegal forward reference to type argument U`. As in other posts, it doesn't seem to be an issue with newer JDK versions.

As per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201687/forward-reference-of-type-parameter-in-java-generics) this was fixed in JDK 1.7

```
public class Whatever <U, T extends U> {
    T specific;
    U moreGeneral;
}
```